# site URL for the facebook like button

Tags: facebook

I have a problem with the Facebook like button. I want the note on user's profile to look something like this: '**User** likes **page** on **site**'.

Site's URL it suppose to be '`http://www.example.com/myapp/`' and the page URL it's '`http://www.example.com/myapp/page.html`'.

I added `<meta property="og:site_name" content="..."/>` in the  of any page and added the like button using `<iframe>`.

I know that there's a solution to specify the canonical URL, but for the page that user likes, not for the site (that is by using `og:url` on the header). Does anyone know how you can specify the site's URL? It somehow automatically points to the domain name, which it's wrong in my case because i need '`http://www.example.com/myapp/`', not '`http://www.example.com`'.

I want the following result: **User** likes '**`http://www.example.com/myapp/page.html`**' on '**`http://www.example.com/myapp`**', not **User** likes '**`http://www.example.com/myapp/page.html`**' on '**`http://www.example.com`**'.

Thank you very much for a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

We've been running into similar problems and in lieu of a `og:site_url` tag have had to get a little hacky. Our solution is to have our base URL (`http://www.example.com` in your example) redirect to the FB page.

As we add more FB pages, we'll need multiple subdomains to support this, so it's not really sustainable, but may solve your problem at least temporarily.